# MySQL: 'on delete cascade' is not working

Tags: mysql, cascade, cascading-deletes

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `parameter` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `parameter`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `parameter`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;


CREATE TABLE `son` (
  `id_parameter` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `son`
  ADD KEY `id_parameter` (`id_parameter`);

ALTER TABLE `son`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `son_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_parameter`) REFERENCES `parameter` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I expected that after deleting a row from 'parameter' the children rows in 'son' table will be removed, but it is not happening..

**EDIT**

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `parameter` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `name` varchar(500) NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> ALTER TABLE `parameter`
    ->   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> ALTER TABLE `parameter`
    ->   MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> 
mysql> CREATE TABLE `son` (
    ->   `id_parameter` int(11) NOT NULL
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> ALTER TABLE `son`
    ->   ADD KEY `id_parameter` (`id_parameter`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> 
mysql> ALTER TABLE `son`
    ->   ADD CONSTRAINT `son_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_parameter`) REFERENCES `parameter` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>   
mysql>   insert into parameter select 1, 'aa';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>   insert into son select 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>   
mysql>   delete from parameter;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from son;
+--------------+
| id_parameter |
+--------------+
|            1 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/221045/1

Comment: Are you certain that you really ran your test after executing all the alter statements in your question?

Comment: No way that it cannot work.

Comment: @P.Salmon I have updated my question.

Comment: Tested it - works fine..with the usual warnings I would post to fiddle but juergen has already done that. what do you get if you select * from parameter?

Comment: @P.Salmon after "select * form parameter" I get empty result